# apex:includescript in html

Tags: html, static-resources

I need to include script in my community header page.for this I need to include html script in html page.what is the equavalent code of below in html

`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jQuery}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.communityResources, 'js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/resource/jQuery></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/resource/communityResources/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
</html>
```

I don't think you actually need to put the type in there, but that's what Visual Force will generate.

Also, here's a link to the documentation for more detail:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_includeScript.htm

Comment: I am using it in header of customer community which only accepts html,jpg,gif,png

Comment: @sf.dev but script is always js :/, do you mean the customer community does not accept .js?

Comment: @rao it accepts js but not visualforce tags like apex:includescript

Comment: The above is html. Create an html document, put the above code in it and upload it as Document into Salesforce. When you choose the community header, that Document should appear in the lookup field.